# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sqrt{n^2+1} - \sqrt[3]{n^3+1}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to test the convergence of
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sqrt{n^2+1} - \sqrt[3]{n^3+1}\right)$$
The ratio test yields and inconclusive $1$. I am able to show $\sqrt{n^2+1} - \sqrt[3]{n^3+1} < 1$ but this is not enough for convergence. One idea would be to rearrange the expression so that it is of the form ${1 \over f(n)}$ and then show that $\text{deg}f > 1$. With the fact that $\sum{1 \over n^s}$ converges if $s>1$ this would give me convergence. So, we could use the formula for $a^3-b^3$ and then the formula for $a^2-b^2$. Is there a quicker way?

Comment: Have you tried some binomial expansion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \sqrt{n^2-1}-\sqrt[3]{n^3-1} = \left(n-\sqrt[3]{n^3-1}\right)-\left(n-\sqrt{n^2-1}\right)\tag{1} $$
so, due to $\frac{a^2-b^2}{a-b}=(a+b)$ and $\frac{a^3-b^3}{a-b}=(a^2+ab+b^2)$ we have:
$$\left(n-\sqrt[3]{n^3-1}\right)\leq \frac{1}{n^2},\qquad \left(n-\sqrt{n^2-1}\right)\geq \frac{1}{2n}\tag{2} $$
and these inequalities ensure that the given series is divergent.

Comment: Great answer, simple and elegant.

Answer (score 5):

Hints: factorize a $n$ out of the parenthesis and use the Taylor expansions
$$
\sqrt{1+n^{-2}}=1+\frac12n^{-2}+O(n^{-4}),\qquad  \sqrt[3]{1+n^{-3}}=1+\frac13n^{-3}+O(n^{-6})
$$
You should obtain a divergent series because of the terms $ n\cdot\frac12 n^{-2}$.

Comment: Are we now done with the rapid-fire edits?

Comment: I think so :-p Just fixed a couple obvious typos. Unfortunately crossed the stream with the OP.

Comment: Helps to notice the radius of convergence for the binomial expansion.